# Unexpected behavior - Does java perform compile time optimization here?

Tags: java, static

Please see this piece of code:

```
class Ideone
{
    static int value = 3;

    Ideone getIdeone()
    {
        System.out.println("getIdeone() called");
        return null;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Ideone ideone = new Ideone();
        System.out.println(ideone.getIdeone().value);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> getIdeone() called
>
> 3

Ideone link [here](http://ideone.com/fAdHJv)

As you must have observed, I am making call to `getIdeone()` which returns `null` and then fetching `value` from the null object.

What is going on here? Does compiler perform some compile-time optimization and fetches `value` directly from the class, reason being it is static?

Comment: You are **NOT** accessing the instance value. So, no problem if the instance is `null`.Static values can even be accessed through non-instantiated reference like `Ideone id; id.value`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because `value` is a `static` field, you don't need an instance to access it, so `null` will suffice. It is indeed taken directly from the class.

The compiler warns you about this already:

> The static field Ideone.value should be accessed in a static way

---

As a bonus exercise, look what happens when subclasses are involved. The code at the bottom will give this output:

> getIdeone() in Test called
>
> 3

(so *not* `5`), even though (*at runtime*) the `getIdeone()` is expected to return a `Test`. This is because the compiler already turned this into a call to the static field of `Ideone` - it doesn't matter what happens at runtime.

```
public class Ideone {
    static final int value = 3;

    Ideone getIdeone() {
        System.out.println("getIdeone() called");
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        Ideone ideone = new Ideone().new Test();
        System.out.println(ideone.getIdeone().value);
    }

    class Test extends Ideone {
        static final int value = 5;

        @Override
        Test getIdeone() {
            System.out.println("getIdeone() in Test called");
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```